# Pivot in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

How do i transform the table of format based on the value in the "Col1"
Let the initial table content be

```
Col1    Col2    Cnt     color
----------------------------
1       1       5       green
1       2       0       blue
1       3       7       red
2       1       0       gray
2       2       10      yellow
2       3       8       orange
```

INTO the table of following format

```
c11  d11  e11  color11  c12  d12 e12  color12  c13  d13 e13 color13
------------------------------------------- -----------------------
1    1    5  green       1   2    0    blue     1   3    7   red
2    1    0  gray        2   2    10   yellow   2   3    8   orange
```

the query is used to generate the data set for a report. where i plot the bubble chart for the each of the x,y co-ordinate.

" c11  d11  e11 c12  d12 e12  c13  d13 e13" are the column names in the new dataset. Since the columns could vary dynamically i have quoted as this way.

I use the color to plot the color for each bubble value

Can some one please help in this query?

Comment: Why do you want this? Can you please explain the scenario ?

Comment: There seems at first glance some missing data.  Where does c11, d11 come from?

Comment: There is Pivot operator in SQL 2005 and above
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: I have tried with "SELECT * FROM (SELECT col1, col2, cnt, color FROM @TABLE) T pivot (Max(Cnt) FOR Col2 IN ([1],[2],[3]))". This allows to apply only aggregate function on color column. But i need to have all the values for Color and Cnt also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a PIVOT solution is what you're really after. Instead you can do the following

```
WITH TestData AS
(
SELECT 1 Col1, 1 Col2, 5 Cnt, 'green' color
UNION SELECT 1 , 2 , 0 Cnt, 'blue'
UNION SELECT 1 , 3 , 7 Cnt, 'red'
UNION SELECT 2 , 1 , 0 Cnt, 'gray'
UNION SELECT 2 , 2 , 10 Cnt, 'yellow'
UNION SELECT 2 , 3 , 8 Cnt, 'orange'

)
SELECT 
    t1.col1 c11 , 
    t1.col2 d11 ,
    t1.cnt e11,
    t1.color  color11,
    t2.col1 c12   , 
    t2.col2 d12 ,
    t2.cnt e12,
    t2.color  color12  ,
    t3.col1 c13 , 
    t3.col2 d13 ,
    t3.cnt e13,
    t3.color  color13


FROM 
    TestData t1
    inner join TestData t2 
    ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 
    inner join TestData t3 
    ON t1.Col1 = t3.Col1 
where t1.Col2 = 1
    and t2.Col2 = 2
    and t3.Col2 = 3
```

Which outputs this

```
c11 d11 e11 color11 c12 d12 e12 color12 c13 d13 e13 color13
--- --- --- ------- --- --- --- ------- --- --- --- -------
1   1   5   green   1   2   0   blue    1   3   7   red
2   1   0   gray    2   2   10  yellow  2   3   8   orange

(2 row(s) affected)
```

My guess is that you'll probably need to Dynamically Generate this sql in your solution rather than the static solution I have.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will work on creating dynamic sql to generate the data set. Since i read in blogs about the usage of PIVOT for transforming rows into columns, i was looking for a solution using PIVOT. Thanks again for spending your time in detailed example.

Comment: I have implemented it with dynamic query. Thanks for the help